# What is the equivalent Flex API for JavaScript API "embedSWF"

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I want to render a flex monster SWF file in another SWF file.
COuld anyone let me know what is the equivalent to the following Javascript API in Flex API.

```
swfobject.embedSWF(swfFilePath+"PivotTable.swf",       
"flashcontent", "100%", "500", "10.0.0",swfFilePath+"expressInstall.swf", 
flashvars, params, attributes, swfAdded);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use SWFLoader class, but it's not guaranteed that external component would work when loaded runtime or embedded this way. I would recommend to check documentation of external component regarding embedding it into another Flex application. Maybe you should use SWF package instead for that option.

Comment: I think you should take a look at their docs http://www.flexmonster.com/flash/help/index.html, chapter Pivot in a Flex application, particularly at http://www.flexmonster.com/flash/help/Contents/embed_pivot_in_flex.html